# How to use global groovy variable in external bash script

Tags: bash, groovy

This is what I have in groovy:

```
sh 'echo "'+params.TEST+'"'
echo params.TEST
```

Both returns 'hello world' which is what I'm expecting.
Now I want to use the variable in an external bash script `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "'+params.TEST+'"
```

I extend my groovy script:

```
sh 'echo "'+params.TEST+'"'
echo params.TEST
sh './test.sh'
```

But the last command, the execution of the script is not printing my parameter. What am I missing here? How can I make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try passing it as an argument to the shell script eg.

```
sh 'echo "'+params.TEST+'"'
echo params.TEST
sh './test.sh "' +params.TEST + '"'
```

And use the argument in the shell script as

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

Comment: Thanks, is there maybe a way to use an env var instead of a parameter in my bash script by creating and env var form my global property in groovy?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run external script, your environment will be inherited from parent process. There are two options here:

- create completely new environment (may be risky as you can forget some things)
- create new environment based on parent's one

In both cases you need to manipulate `Map<String, String>` and add your variables into new environment.

**Groovy script (ProcessBuilder):**

```
8< --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- 

def script = "./file.sh"
def pb = new ProcessBuilder(script).inheritIO()

def variable = "Variable value"

Map<String, String> env = pb.environment()
env.put( "variable", variable )

Process p = pb.start()
p.waitFor()

8< --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE ---
```

**Groovy script (execute method):**

```
8< --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE ---

def script = "./file.sh"

def variable = "Variable value"

myenv = new HashMap(System.getenv())
myenv.put("variable", variable )

String[] envarray = myenv.collect { k, v -> "$k=$v" }

def std_out = new StringBuilder()
def std_err = new StringBuilder()

proc = script.execute( envarray, null )

proc.consumeProcessOutput(std_out, std_err)

println std_out

8< --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE ---
```

**Shell script:**

```
8< --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE ---

#!/bin/bash

echo "Hello from script"
echo $variable

8< --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE --- CUT HERE ---
```